# Does method.invoke create a new thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection

I am calling a method using reflection in Java using the `method.invoke` function. Does that `method.invoke` create a new thread or it will run with the current thread?

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not create a new thread.

The [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object...)) don't mention anything about multithreading or being asynchronous, and this is typically a very strong indication that it will be executed in the current thread.

Constructs that may use other threads are typically quite explicit about not making any guarantees as to which thread will execute the code - see the documentation for [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) or [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html)